# How to find a root word in an ArrayList

Tags: java, nlp

I'm working on a NLP project and try to match a specific input with a root in an `ArrayList`.

For example, the user will enter لاعبون and try to find the word لعب in an `ArrayList`, but when i run my code it gives me more than one root.

```
for(String dbData : rootList) {

    //System.out.println(dbData);

    // if(dbData.contains(x)) {
    //     System.out.println(dbData);
    // }

    for (int i = 0; i < dbData.length(); i++) {
        c = dbData.charAt(i);

        for (int j = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
            d = x.charAt(i);

            if (c == d && m != rootList.size()) {
                match = true;
                //System.out.println(dbData);
            } else {
                ++m;
                match = false;           
                //System.out.println("لا يوجد تطابق");
            }

            if(match) { 
                System.out.println(dbData);
                container = dbData;
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could format your code.

Comment: where is m defined?

Comment: variables are undefined. c, d, match and container are self evident but x and m are never given a value. x is the word to match?

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 x is the word to match

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem like a right approach to do stemming. Try the below that is a simple way to find stems in Arabic.

First you need a list of stems, and obviously you have that. 
Then you should need to write the Arabic literature rules and forms that can parse a word to a stem. 
Now you just convert your rules to java regex.
For example if you want to find لعب from لاعبون you should remove ون as it shows person and count, then you should check if لاعب is derived from one of the stems. As you know the forms لاعب is فاعل form of لعب so you should choose لعب.

Comment: i know that but my code try to find if لاعب is derived from لعب it generates لعب and ضرب not only لعب.

Comment: I really don't think your code will work fine! I have a question here are you making an application that stemming is some part if it or you just have to code a stemmer? If it is the first one you can use Apache Lucene Arabic stemmer. But if it is the second let me know and I will edit my answer and give you more hints with code.

Comment: the second one i'm working in a project to extract the POS tags from input word in MSA format so i cannot use any ready made stemmers , i'm studying NLP as a master course and this is my project @Alikbar i'm so grateful for your help